# Is there an alternative to libusb-win32 for 64bit windows?

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, driver, libusb

I've been developing some software which uses the [libusb-win32](http://libusb-win32.sourceforge.net/) library to interact with some USB hardware I've been developing. Now I'm trying to run the same software on windows 64 but the drivers don't seem to work (understandably).

Are there any alternatives for 64 bit Windows I've overlooked?

Comment: The alternative library [is libusb](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/FAQ#libusbwin32_libusbK_and_libusb_project). I don't know your device details, but you can check [this section](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/FAQ#How_to_use_libusb_under_Windows) to see if you need any additional setup. Also, libusb-win32 is in bugfix-only mode, in preference of libusb *(it's written on their sourceforge page)*. And I know, the post is very old, I'm mainly leaving the comment here to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there may be some 64-bit pre-compiled version available [here](http://www.4shared.com/account/file/41034572/1c815fbc/SIXAXIS_libusb-win64.html) and [here](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/windows_backend).

**[Edit]** Oops. Looks like this is already provided for in libusb-win32 in [the latest release](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb-win32/files/). 64bit and 32bit are both provided in the device driver package.

Answer (score 2):

The last version 1.2.6.0 does not work in Windows 10, and presumably not in Windows 8/8.1. Works fine in 32/64 bit Windows 7. Development appears to have stopped in 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the similar issues with windows builds in Go.

As I did not find this easy to figure out I will be a little verbose here to ensure what works for me is clear for the novice that stumbles across this post.

Windows 10 X64

- Install msys2
- install either 32 bit `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain` or 64 bit `pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`
- check version of libusb that installed `pacman -Q | grep libusb`

  mingw-w64-x86_64-libusb 1.0.23-1
- create `/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/libusb-1.0.pc`

```
#lib-usb-1.0.pc
prefix=/mingw64
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libusb-1.0
Description: C API for USB device access from Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, OpenBSD/NetBSD and Solaris userspace

#update version to match
Version: 1.0.23
Libs: -L${libdir} -llibusb-1.0
Libs.private: 
Cflags: -I${includedir}/libusb-1.0
```

- create directory `/mingw64/include/libusb-1.0`
- download correct version of libusb.h and extract to
  `/mingw64/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h`